# Unable to ask a question on stackoverflow after a silly mistake

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, undelete

I am accepting that this is a duplicate question of many others. But I want to fix my problem, I know very well that if someone posts many low quality questions or questions that do not meet the standards of site, then he/she will be blocked from asking questions.

Also if someone delete the questions from the site then it may be a reason of blocking. Or many other reasons like IP conflict, account conflict and many more.

**What in my case:**

I removed a question from site that did not get any answer, any upvote or any downvote.
But I got the block from site after 15 days of that removal by further asking the questions only not for others. But I have a question: why after 15 days?

**Reason of removing that question:**

I did not get any answer on that question, so I think that if I ask the same question again then it will violate the terms & condition of site.

So I decided to remove it, and after one day I have asked the same question and got the answer. But at that time I was not aware that removal also violate the rule.

**But What I am requesting now:**  Now I know my mistake and will never repeat it, So give some help that do a fix to my problem. I am trying to undelete the deleted one but getting failed.

I tried many solution from the same questions have been asked here but did not get fix.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a genuine request, I'm sure your account will get unblocked soon. From your description it doesn't look like you were abusing the system and this ban might be short lived once reviewed by Mods.

Comment: Sorry, from your question is not really clear what's your problem: you got a question ban, as suggest your title? Or you don't know(you're not able) to un-delete that question?

Comment: @Hanky mods can't remove the ban. The OP got several downvoted questions and not a single upvoted question, and maybe more than one deleted downvoted questions, which have greater impact on the ban.

Comment: @Robi if you can't undelete it means it was deleted by other users, post link here so we can help you improve it then flag for moderator who can undelete and reopen.

Comment: @Adinia, I am unable to post new question, and also unable to do a undo on deleted one.

Comment: Hey All, Automatically I got the deleted question back. But still I am unable to post a new question.Pls do some help

Answer (score 3):

"Yaa I am accepting that this is a duplicate question of many other's. But I want to fix my problem"

That's a problem right there. If your question is a duplicate question of many others you should do a search on the site and read the answers to those other questions, not just ask it again.

Right now well over 197% of new SO questions are "how do I use a join statement", and a further 123% are "how do I convert rows to columns" (or at least that's how it seems).

Comment: @ Mr. ben, I did the same. But the answer that you have given, In actual this is not a answer, this is a suggestion. So next time use comment instead of such type answers.

Comment: Admittedly the support tag can be used for personalised problems. Also; is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: +1 for 'a further 123% are "how do I convert rows to columns"', though Robi's reply also gets a +1